# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for method that is not used

Tags: java, maven, nosuchmethoderror

I'm pretty new to Maven and I'm having an issue with a `NoSuchMethodError` at runtime for a method that is not used anywhere in my project after merging my work with someone else's, particularly regarding `com.google.inject.util.Types.collectionOf`.

The new work has to do with fixing the project's executable jar, so I don't think any modifications had to do with guice. My local repo contains the exact same versions of the guice and multibinding jars as it did when I ran my previous version of this project and no obvious changes have been made to the pom files.

I am familiar with this kind of error and have fixed it before but this time I cannot figure out the issue. Here is the start of my error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.util.Types.collectionOf(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Ljava/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType;
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder.collectionOfProvidersOf(Multibinder.java:202)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.<init>(Multibinder.java:283)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.<init>(Multibinder.java:258)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder.newRealSetBinder(Multibinder.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder.newSetBinder(Multibinder.java:132)
```

Comment: This sometimes happens when a jar depends on another jar (a transient dependency) If people play nice they all come in together.  Sometimes not.  What is this particular artifact?

Comment: @MaxPower the artifact in question appears to be guice. It seems as though maybe guice-multibindings needs collectionOf but I never got this problem with my other version of this project. The versions of guice and guice-multibindings in the local repo are both 4.1.0

Comment: Have you tried explicitly adding both to your pom.xml?

Comment: @MaxPower I just did that and it works! I thought that having them declared as dependencies elsewhere would do the trick, but I guess not. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

This question is old and already answered in comment, I was also facing same issue and base on comments, I did the things and my issue got resolved.
So just to help other new users posting here.

When I was facing the issue, the my dependency in pom was as below.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now after adding one more dependency as below, it's got resolved and worked fine.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```